# Why mmap fails to allocate executable page on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault, executable, mmap

I am trying to run the code example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974980 on macOS 13, and the program gives segmentation fault.

In fact, let's simplify the program linked above to

```c
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<stddef.h>
int main(){
    size_t size = 100;
    char* buf = (char*) mmap(NULL, (size_t) size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *buf = 'a';
    return 0;
}
```

And even this simple program gives segmentation fault on macOS. The mmap does not return null pointer, but the pointer cannot be accessed. Removing `PROT_EXEC` fixes the problem, but the whole point is to allocate executable memory. Why is it not working? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need at least `MAP_JIT`, but even that won’t save you on Apple Silicon:

[This Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-just-in-time-compilers-to-apple-silicon?language=objc) states:

> When memory protection is enabled, a thread cannot write to a memory
> region and execute instructions in that region at the same time. Apple
> silicon enables memory protection for all apps, regardless of whether
> they adopt the Hardened Runtime. Intel-based Mac computers enable
> memory protection only for apps that adopt the Hardened Runtime.

It goes on to explain what you need to do. It’s a bit long to quote, but it boils down to using `pthread_jit_write_protect_np` to disable memory protection before writing, and to enable it again before executing.