# What's the protection flags of memory allocated by malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094934/loading-raw-code-from-c-program),memory allocated by `malloc` at least have `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`,otherwise the contaned function can't be executed .

`man malloc` doesn't mention anything about protection thus the question.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right thread? I don't see anything about PROT_READ or PROT_EXEC there. I thought those two were related to mmap. (See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mmap.html)

Comment: @Catcall ,that's why I say `malloc` returned memory implicitly has `PROT_READ` or `PROT_EXEC` on,as it doesn't have to `mprotect(p, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC)` while memory returned by `mmap` has to.

Answer (score 6):

`malloc()` will normally return memory with read and write permissions. Some architectures (e.g: older x86) may not allow disabling execute permission in a straightforward way, but that's just a defficiency of the platform.

If you want to execute code from memory you allocated, you'll have to give execute permissions explicitly, and possibly you'll have to remove write permissions, since having both write and execute permissions on the same memory is considered potentially dangerous on some systems (commonly referred as W^X).

There have been several other threads on executing code from memory allocated by the programmer:

[Allocate executable ram in c on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125756/allocate-executable-ram-in-c-on-linux)
[Is it possible to execute code from the stack in standard C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755491/is-it-possible-to-execute-code-from-the-stack-in-standard-c)

Comment: do you have a machine that has the NX bit to test it out?

Answer (score 6):

`malloc` is not the right tool for allocating memory for code. You should use `mmap`, and depending on the paranoid security policies on your system, you might need to use `mprotect` too for changing the permissions.

Among the reasons `malloc` is not the right tool:

- Permissions are set only with page granularity, but memory obtained by `malloc` is unlikely to be page-aligned, and thus you'll end up setting permissions on adjacent memory too, possibly breaking things.
- If you don't restore the old permissions before calling `free`, you might break `malloc`'s internals.

Comment: Regarding *Permissions are set only with page granularity*,do you mean memory returned by `void *mmap(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);` is always in unit of page? Doesn't seem to be garunteed by `length` parameter though.

Comment: @Je Rog: yes, mmap() creates memory mappings, which have page-granularity (except on !MMU systems)

Comment: And "!mmu" cannot conform to POSIX (which requires memory protection).

Comment: @ninjalj ,the `length` doesn't need to be a multiple of page,how come? Does that mean if we mmap `4000` bytes ,then `96` bytes will be wasted?

Comment: @Je Rog: They'll be mapped, see `/proc/<pid>/maps` on Linux.

Comment: Length will be rounded up to page size multiple.

Comment: `A file is mapped in multiples of the page size. For a file that is not a multiple of the page size, the remaining memory
       is zeroed when mapped, and writes to that region are not written out to the file. The effect of changing the size of the
       underlying file of a mapping on the pages that correspond to added or removed regions of the file is unspecified.`

Comment: @R..,not rounded,I think **wasted** is more accurate since the effect of writing to the extra 96 bytes is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to call `mprotect` to set the `PROT_EXEC` flag yourself, after the memory has been allocated.

[$ man mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect)

Comment: seems not,see the linked paragraph,it doesn't involve `mprotect` which indicates memory returned by `malloc` already has `PROT_EXEC` on.

Comment: @Je Rog: OK - I'm surprised that Linux sets `PROT_EXEC` by default for malloc'd memory - it may be that other operating systems take a more defensive approach - if your question is Linux-specific then you should probably tag it `linux`.

Comment: Yeah that's the case,I want to know what other flags are set but `man malloc` gives no clue. Also,I don't know whether it's linux specific,so I don't think it proper to add that tag.

Comment: @Je Rog: it's probably best not to make any assumptions, particularly if you care about portability and being future-proof.

Comment: Older x86 CPUs don't have execute permission bits for pages, so usually read permission implied execute permission. Newer CPUs have an NX (non-execute) bit.

Answer (score 0):

The malloc() library function is specified by the C language standard, so it is the same on all operating systems. The memory protection is a function of the processor and operating system, so it is done differently on Windows, Linux, etc.

The way this works has changed over the years since malloc() was defined. I remember when most processors did not support a separate "executable" permission for memory - if it was readable, it was executable. Many embedded systems don't have any memory protection at all, all memory can be read, written, and executed. The malloc() function works the same way in all these cases.